# Boxed view with picture, make image thumbnail on left

Tags: css

I created a boxed view of users with avatars:

[image]

What style should I change to display this avatar more compact, in one row with user details (moved text in paint :) ):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, made it with jQuery:

```
            var styleboxes = jQuery("td.ms-stylebox");

            jQuery.each(styleboxes, function () {

                var avatarRow = jQuery(this).find("tr:first");
                var secondCellInAvaRow = jQuery(avatarRow).find("td:last");

                var textRows = jQuery(this).find("tr:not(:first)");
                var clonedTextRows = jQuery(textRows).clone();
                clonedTextRows = jQuery(clonedTextRows).wrapAll("<td><table></table></td>");

                // place text rows on the same line with photo
                jQuery(secondCellInAvaRow).after(clonedTextRows);
                textRows.remove();
            }
```